# VPN Client Connection each other

Tags: iptables

I have l2tp vpn on Digital Ocean, then connect the device. I want each device connect each other.

For example :

192.168.42.10 can connect to 192.168.42.11

This for tunneling purposes.

IPtables rules :

```
 GNU nano 2.2.6           File: /etc/iptables.rules

Completed on Thu Dec 26 15:07:38 2019
 Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Dec 26 15:07:38 2019
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1701 -m policy --dir in --pol none -j DROP
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 500,4500 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1701 -m policy --dir in --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1701 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o ppp+ -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i ppp+ -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.42.0/24 -d 192.168.42.0/24 -i ppp+ -o ppp+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.43.0/24 -i eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHE$
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.43.0/24 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DROP
```

Comment: What does `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` return?

Comment: net.ipv4.ip_forrward = 1